# How to take the derivative of linear algebra inside a norm

Tags: linear-algebra, derivatives, normed-spaces

If I have an equation like this...

$$
L(X_s, y_s) = \frac{1}{2}|| y_t - K_{ts}(K_{ss} + \lambda I)^{-1}y_s ||^2
$$

and I want to find the minimum with respect to $y_s$, how could I go about differentiating what is inside of the norm?

Comment: expand the objective function out of the norm based on the fact that it is the sum of its contents squared, and take the derivative of that expanded form

Answer (score 0):

$\def\p{\partial}$
To reduce the vistual clutter, define the following variables
$$\eqalign{
A &= K_{ts}(K_{ss} + \lambda I)^{-1} \\
x &= y_s \\
b &= y_t \\
}$$
Then the objective function can be written in the standard form
$$\eqalign{
L &= \tfrac 12 \|Ax-b\|^2 \\
}$$
whose gradient and optimum
$$\eqalign{
\frac{\p L}{\p x}
 &= A^T(Ax-b) \quad\xrightarrow{\frac{\p L}{\p x}=0}\quad 
x = (A^TA)^{-1}A^Tb \\
}$$
have been derived many times on this site
(aka the *Normal Equation* of the system).